# Trying to open .gitignore to edit it in text editor but cannot find location of file on OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I created a new rails app using "new app_name" and I'm trying to edit the .gitignore file but can't find it in my app folder. Where can I find it? I have Git installed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.gitignore` is in the *root* of the project, not in the `app` subdirectory. First open the terminal and go inside your directory.

You'll need to use `ls -a` to show hidden files.

Then use `open .gitignore`

Answer (score 0):

Dotfiles are hidden.  Use `ls -a` to see it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do I type that into the terminal? When I do, I see the file but how do open it from there? Thanks again.